# SQL join with count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables; articles and article_shares (how many times an article has been shared)

I want to show all articles by a user (id 63) and how many times they have shared the article (this could be 0)

Articles:

```
article_id - user_id  - title - date
```

Article_shares

```
article_id
```

I'm trying the following but it only returning the one row where there are shares but I want to show all, even if the number of shares is 0 (there are 7 articles in this case)

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%d/%m/%y') as article_date, count(*) 
from articles a 
join article_shares ash on ash.article_id = a.article_id
where (a.user_id = '63') order by a.article_title asc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your join to a left join

Something like

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%d/%m/%y') as article_date, count(*)  
from articles a  
left join article_shares ash on ash.article_id = a.article_id 
where (a.user_id = '63') order by a.article_title asc
```

Have a look at this example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1bb1/3/0)

Also maybe have a look at [Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: Since the OP included *even if the number of shares is 0* indicates that the OP probably wants to count shares not rows. Since you have `count(*)` it will always be > 0. You might want to make it `count(ash.article_id)` instead

Answer (score 3):

Just do `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. It will create NULL entries for articles with no shares.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `join` condition as `LEFT JOIN` and try. This will return the articles share even if the article_id is null in them.

Answer (score 2):

you should use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%d/%m/%y') as article_date, count(*) 
from articles a 
left join article_shares ash on ash.article_id = a.article_id
where (a.user_id = '63') order by a.article_title asc
```